# How do you return items from ArrayList that is stored in a different file?

Tags: java, file, arraylist, return-value

so the code I currently have can return a reference to the object in the array but wont display the data inside of it. The first bit of code is the main file which the user inputs the data, but the object reference only returns the last object the user entered, what i need is for the array to be searched and if it is found with the item display the data that is stored with that object.

the first file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Inv
{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        String str;
        char c;
        int n=0;


        //Product product  = new Product();


        System.out.println("        INVENTORY MANAGEMENT SYSTEM");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("1. ADD PRODUCT DATA");
        System.out.println("2. VIEW PRODUCT DATA");
        System.out.println("3. VIEW REPRLENISHMENT STRATEGY");
        System.out.println("===============================================");
        System.out.println("4. EXIT PROGRAM");

        while(n!=4)
        {
            System.out.print("\n Please enter option 1-4 to continue...: ");
            n = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());

            if (n>4||n<1)
            {
                System.out.print("Invalid input, please try again...");
                continue;
            }
            if (n==1)
            {
                str="y";
                while(str.equals("y")||str.equals("Y"))
                {

                    Inv.addItem();
                    System.out.print("Would you like to enter another product ? (Y or N) : ");
                    str = console.next();
                }   
                continue;
            }
            if (n==2)
            {
                str="y";
                while(str.equals("y")||str.equals("Y"))
                {
                    Inv.prodData();
                    System.out.println("\n***************************************************\n");
                    System.out.print("Stay viewing this page? (Y or N) ");
                    str = console.next();

                }
                continue;
            }
            else

            if (n==3)
            {
                System.out.print("View Replenishment Strategy.");
                continue;
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\nThank you for using this inventory management software.\n");
        System.out.print("Developed by Xavier Edwards");
        System.out.println("\n***************************************************\n");

    }

    public static Product product;
    public static Store store;
    public static void addItem ()
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        product = new Product();
        store = new Store();

        String desc, id, str="";
        double price = 0, sUpPrice = 0, unitCost = 0, inventoryCost = 0;
        int stock = 0, demand = 0;

        //if (product == null) //If product 1 is empty
        //{
            System.out.print("Please enter product description between 3 to 10 characters...: ");
            desc = console.next();
            desc = desc.toLowerCase();
            product.setName(desc);

            if ((desc.length() < 3 || desc.length() > 10))
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make description between 3 to 10 characters.\n");
                System.out.println("Try again with different input. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter price in $ : ");
            price = console.nextDouble();
            product.setPrice(price);

            if (price < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
                System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter set up price. $ : ");
            sUpPrice = console.nextDouble();
            product.setsUpPrice(sUpPrice);

            if (sUpPrice < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
                System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter unit- cost. $ : ");
            unitCost = console.nextDouble();
            product.setunitCost(unitCost);

            if (unitCost < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
                System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter the inventory cost. $ : ");
            inventoryCost = console.nextDouble();
            product.setinvCost(inventoryCost);

            if (inventoryCost < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
                System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter the amount in stock : ");
            stock = console.nextInt();
            product.setstock(stock);

            if (stock < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
                System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.print("Please enter the demand of the product : ");
            demand = console.nextInt();
            product.setdRate(demand);

            if (demand < 0)
            {
                System.out.println("\nThis Input is incorrect. Please make sure attributes are positve numbers\n");
                System.out.println("Because of incorrect input, program will restart. ");
                System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
                Inv.addItem();
            }

            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            System.out.print(desc +" Product was added successfully ");
            System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
            store.add(product);

        //}
    }

    public static void prodData()
    {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pOption, str;

        System.out.print("\nEnter product description to view the data...\n");
        pOption = console.next();

        if (product == null)
        {
            System.out.println("\nThere is no information on this product.\n");

            System.out.println("\nWould you like to try again? (Y or N) \n");
            str = console.next();
            Inv.prodData();
        }

        System.out.println("The information for the product is..... ");
        System.out.println("\n*****************************************\n");
        System.out.println(store.ProductList.get(0));
        if (product.equals(store.ProductList.get(0)))
        {
            System.out.println("Product description : "+product.getName());
            System.out.println("Price : $ "+product.getPrice());
            System.out.println("Set-up Price : $ "+product.getsUpPrice());
            System.out.println("Unit Cost : $ "+product.getunitCost());
            System.out.println("Inventory Cost : $ "+product.getinvCost());
            System.out.println("Amount of Stock : "+product.getstock());
            System.out.println("Amount of Stock : "+product.getdRate());
        }*/
    }

}
```

The second file which is where the array list is made and objects stored.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store{
    public ArrayList <Product> ProductList = new ArrayList<Product> ();

    public Store()
    {
        //ArrayList = "";

    }

    public void add(Product product)
    {           
        ProductList.add(product);
    }

    public Product getProduct(String prodName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.size(); i++) {
            if (ProductList.get(i).getName().equals(prodName)) {
                return ProductList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
 }

}
```

Code for the storing of particular user entries

```
public class Product
{
    public String name;
    public double price, sUpPrice, unitCost, invCost;
    public int stock, demand;


    public Product()
    {
        name = "";
        price = 0;
        sUpPrice = 0;
        unitCost = 0;
        invCost = 0;
        stock = 0;
        demand = 0;

    }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setPrice(double price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
        public double getPrice() {
            return this.price;
        }   
        public void setsUpPrice(double sUpPrice) {
            this.sUpPrice = sUpPrice;
        }
        public double getsUpPrice() {
            return this.sUpPrice;
        }   
        public void setunitCost(double unitCost) {
            this.unitCost = unitCost;
        }
        public double getunitCost() {
            return this.unitCost;
        }   
        public void setinvCost(double invCost) {
            this.invCost = invCost;
        }
        public double getinvCost() {
            return this.invCost;
        }
        public void setstock(int stock) {
            this.stock = stock;
        }
        public int getstock() {
            return this.stock;
        }
        public void setdRate(int demand) {
            this.demand = demand;
        }
        public int getdRate() {
            return this.demand;
        }

}
```

so thats the code within another file called product.java

Comment: your topic is return an arraylist stored in a file bt i dont see any instance in your code related to reading or writing a file

Comment: sorry what i mean is that where the array list is at is in a file called store.java and the main bit of code is in a file called inv.java if that makes better sense

Comment: so you need to store your data at class store and get back data from class store , so that you can get data from store class from any class in your project

Comment: yes thats basically it, as you can see from the first bit of code, all the way down the bottom, i need it to be returned in that method when it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the user to type in a product name, and then display all the product's data.

You should probably use your `getProduct` method.

```
product = store.getProduct(pOption);
if (product != null){
    System.out.println("Product description : "+product.getName());
    System.out.println("Price : $ "+product.getPrice());
    System.out.println("Set-up Price : $ "+product.getsUpPrice());
    System.out.println("Unit Cost : $ "+product.getunitCost());
    System.out.println("Inventory Cost : $ "+product.getinvCost());
    System.out.println("Amount of Stock : "+product.getstock());
    System.out.println("Amount of Stock : "+product.getdRate());
}else{
    System.out.println("\nThere is no information on this product.\n");
    System.out.println("\nWould you like to try again? (Y or N) \n");
    str = console.next();
    Inv.prodData();
}
```

Comment: thankyou your code works for returning the product information but only if there is a single product in the list, when i enter in 2 items to the list, then the first item is wiped, how would i go about fixing that?

Comment: Do these 2 items have the same name?

Comment: i've added the final part of the whole project to the original question, this is another file

Comment: Do you mean that, if you enter 2 products, you can only retrieve the newest one?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Inv {


    //read data from any way you prefer and call the methods on store class
    //since the class methods and the productlist are marked as static
    //every class on your project is accessing and changing the same productlist

    Store.add("your product object");
    Store.getProduct("your name");


}


class Store{
    public static ArrayList <product> ProductList = new ArrayList<product> (); 

    public static void add(product product){
    ProductList.add(product);
    }

    public static product getProduct(String prodName) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ProductList.size(); i++) {
            if (ProductList.get(i).getName().equals(prodName)) {
                return ProductList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

       //implement new static methods to remove products from productlist
    public static removeProduct(String name){
       //code to remove product
    }


    public static removeAll(){
    //code to clear the productlist
    }


}
```

you need to follow this approach in your code explanation is provided inside the comments